# Why we use SURF descriptors?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, surf, feature-descriptor

I just studied about `SURF` and going for its implementation , but i still didn't get why we use `descriptor` in it , i understand about `keypoints` in it , their purpose , but when we extract the keypoints than why we need to go for `descriptors` ? and whats their importance and role in recognition ?

I read about it from paper , through forums and net , but i didn't get it through that equations , I just want to know about it in simple words as someone may not good in understanding the equations.